# copying pandas dataframe without messing it when extending list to a column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want a different copy of dataframe to extend a list to its column 'parents' but problem is copying procedures that I know dont work so what should I do?

none of lines #1 to #4 (which are for copying dataframe) work properly and make mess with my main df 'moves' when I run line #5 but in running line#6(#5 commented) they work just fine so problem is with putting lists in coulmns in pandas dataframes

```
moves=pd.DataFrame({"first":[0],"second":[5],'done':[0],'parents':[[-1]],'id':[0]})
# tdf=moves.copy(deep=True) #1
# tdf=moves.copy(deep=False) #2
# tdf=moves.loc[:] #3
# tdf=moves[:] #4
i=0
tdf.loc[i,'parents'].extend([moves.loc[i,'id']]) #5
# tdf.loc[i,'first']=4 #6
print(moves)
```

and result of printing 'moves' would have [-1,0] in it but if the copying had been done well it would have [-1] as before.
and I know line#2 is not for original copying and it would reference so ignore line #2.

Answer (score 0):

If u wish to create a new data frame with same data you can write below
trf=moves

And then make changes as per your requirement

Comment: result of printing 'moves' would have [-1,0] in it but if the copying had been done well it would have [-1] as before.

Answer (score 0):

Copy moves dataframe to a new dataframe (tdf) and perform extend operation.

```
moves=pd.DataFrame({"first":[0],"second":[5],'done':[0],'parents':[[-1]],'id':[0]})
i=0
tdf = moves
tdf.loc[i,'parents'].extend([moves.loc[i,'id']]) #5
# tdf.loc[i,'first']=4 #6
```

The above code gives the following value for tdf

```
 first  second  done  parents  id
0      0       5     0  [-1, 0]   0
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: no I want 
`
 first  second  done  parents  id
0      0       5     0  [-1]   0
`
when I print(moves)